# read data from a CSV file with multiple indices and conditions in Matlab

Tags: matlab, csv, indices, multiple-conditions

i have a bunch of daily data in an excel file where the entries are more than 20,000 for many stations. The data is distributed into columns and rows, each row is the station name, latitude, longitude, altitude, date, and observations.

What i want is to read the data for each station into a new matrix that starts from 2012 till 2013, also the corresponding station that meet the condition name, latitude, longitude, and elevation should be stored in another table or csv, or excel file. i have added a picture of the data structure for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first step is to import the data in matlab. Then you can play with indexing and subsample your data.

Did you manage to import your data in matlab already?

If you have a recent version of matlab, you can open the import data tool by right click on the csv file in the file explorer window.

Comment: Actually i have loaded the data as table and was able to write a loop that can go through all the station using strcmp and pick the stations. now i am facing some error in the code. if you can look and see how can i solve it.

Comment: a = 1;
 stn = 1;
 for i = 2:24  %8229
     
     
     if (strcmp (ddata(i,1),ddata(i-1,1)))==0
         
         dataout = ['data',stn];
           
        dataout(a,:) = ddata(i,:)
        
     elseif (strcmp (ddata(i,1),ddata(i-1,1)))==1
         
         dataout = ['data',stn];
         dataout(a,:) =ddata(i,:);
         
     end
                  

     a = a + 1;
 
 end